# Should I create different projects for iOS(Game Center) and Android(Google Play Games)?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have an Android Game made with Unity that is succeeding and now I want to launch it for iOS.

Should I have two Unity projects, one for Android and another for iOS, or can I do it with an only project?

I use Google Play Games and I want to use Game Center for iOS, and I don't know if it all could work in a single project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I have two Unity projects, one for Android and another for iOS,
>   or can I do it with an only project?

**No**. You only need one project. Multiple projects will be very hard to maintain and that's unnecessary.

Use Unity's directives such as `UNITY_IOS` and `UNITY_ANDROID` to make Unity include your Game Center code for iOS and Google Play Games code for Android during *compile-time.*  See [*Platform dependent compilation*](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) for other directives.

---

You can also do this during runtime by checking [`Application.platform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer.html) with `RuntimePlatform.Android` and `RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer`.